# How to display a sample of digit as binary image?

Tags: python, matlab

I am very new to machine learning and as a part of my project, i have to do the handwritten digit classification.

My "**digit_0.txt**" is a text file with `0' and`1' representing the original foreground and background of digit 0.

It looks something like this:

0011000

0100100

0011000

How can i display this text file as a binary image with black background and white foreground representing my digit in Python ?

I have done this in matlab using imwrite command.

Thank you !

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to do and how that is related to machine learning. Usually in machine learning you would convert images to text and not the other way around.

Comment: You are right actually but i was trying to do it other way around also that's why asked it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an assignment, but if it's not:

There is a repository containing TONS of handwritten digits, you can use this data set to train your classifier.

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = None
with open('digit_0.txt', 'r') as digit_stream:
    for row_data in digit_stream:
        row_data = row_data.replace('\n', '')
        row_img = np.zeros((1, len(row_data)), dtype=np.uint8)
        for idx, bit in enumerate(row_data):
            if bit == '1':
                row_img[0, idx] = 255
            else:
                row_img[0, idx] = 0
        if img is None:
            img = row_img
        else:
            img = np.vstack((img, row_img))
cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `imshow` function in the `matplotlib` library

[Check this link for more info](http://matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)